# How to order posts tag by tag in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, filter

I want to order my posts by tags with only one WP_Query()

In my WP_Query I would like to display
2 posts with tags 'portrait'

2 posts with tags 'paysage'

2 posts with tags 'portrait'

2 posts with tags 'paysage'

2 posts with tags 'portrait'

2 posts with tags 'paysage'

Etc...

And I need to order these posts by recents.

What is the query to do that ?

Thanks

PS : Sorry I cannot use code because I'm with my iPhone.

Comment: Other people also had this problem: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-display-two-most-recent-posts-per-category-on-the-home-page

Answer (score 0):

Your problem maps to the popular `greatest-n-per-group` SQL problem, which maps to a not really trivial query (in MySQL at least, which WordPress uses).
See for example http://rickosborne.org/blog/2008/01/sql-getting-top-n-rows-for-a-grouped-query/ for such a query. I think it's not possible to feed WP_Query with any parameters which could internally generate a similar complex SQL query.

You will probably have to create a custom MySQL query based on this example:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata#Example_2

and by using the WordPress database schema: http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Database_Diagram